# Filter array by index

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to delete an object from my array, using the index:

```
  case DELETE_DRINK:
            return {
                drinks: state.drinks.filter((drink, i) => drink[i] != payload)
            }
```

However, the array stays the same, any ideas?

Here is my array:

[image]

Comment: What is "drinks"?

Comment: `state.drinks.filter((drink, i) => drink[i] != payload)` why trying to access `drink[i]` drink is already the element you want

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `splice` to remove an item by index:

```
array.splice(index, 1);  // splices the item at index
```

**Edit: the following method does not mutate the original `array`**:

```
var missing = array.slice().splice(index, 1);  // first clones the array, and then splices off the item at index
```

Comment: Be careful not to mutate the state though

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have drinks inside, not arrays, you could use the element itself for checking. The first parameter of the callback of [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is

> The current element being processed in the array.

```
state.drinks.filter(drink => drink != payload)
//                           ^^^^^             // without index
```

Comment: Thanks, so I can remove the object from its position

Answer (score 0):

```
state.drinks.filter((drink, i, drinks) => drinks[i] != payload)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
case actionTypes.DELETE_NOTE:
  return state.filter(note => note.id !== action.payload.id);
 case actionTypes.ANOTHER_WAY_TO_DELETE:
  return state.map(lane => {
    if (arrayFIRST.id === action.payload.id) { // id from second array
      // THEN DO YOUR STAFF
    }
```

There is working example! You did to much complicated!